# Use of "for that matter"

Tags: word-usage, phrases

How can I use phrase "For that matter"?

> Ex: I started going to gym and wake up early for that matter. Is it ok?

Can you shed some light on it with a few examples?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[For that matter](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for-that-matter) is used to

> show that a statement is true in another situation:
>
> Ming's never been to Spain, or to any European country for that matter.

In your example sentence, "I started going to gym and wake up early for that matter."

You probably want to give the reason for waking up early (because you go to gym). In this case it would be better to say "so" or "that's why".

> "I started going to gym **so** I wake up early."
>
> "I started going to gym **that's why** I wake up early."

[So](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/so?s=t) is an adverb one of its meanings is

> for this or that reason; hence; therefore:
>
> She is ill, and so cannot come to the party.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please just tell me difference b/w this & above sentence _Ming's never been to Spain, or to any European country_. If I remove 'for that matter'.

Comment: The meaning stays the same. "for that matter" just emphasises that *Ming has never been to **any** European country*

Comment: @Arvindraja https://www.google.pt/search?q=for+that+matter&oq=for+that+matter&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.4080j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 This link might help you further

Comment: @Arvindraja also take a look at https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13602/the-exact-meaning-of-for-that-matter which is on our sister site as ws2 recommended

Answer (score 1):

It is OED sense 3e of that use of ***matter*** as an indeterminate noun, "comparable to *thing*".

***For that matter*** is an idiomatic equivalent of *so far as that is concerned*.

The full OED entry is as follows:

> 3e. (as) for that matter: so far as that is concerned (more recently
>   also introducing an additional supporting observation, esp. one
>   offered in refutation of a position).
>
> 1575   G. Gascoigne Glasse of Gouernem. iv. iii. sig. Ji   Dicke. I
>   trust maister Philosarchus fees will be sufficient to set both thee
>   and me a floate, and make vs as braue as the best. Eccho. Tushe, as
>   for that matter, if he do not another shall.
>
> a1633   F. Godwin Man in Moone (1638) 3   Mine enemies gave it out to
>   my disgrace that I was his horse-keepers boy. But for that matter I
>   shall referre my selfe unto the report of the Count.
>
> 1673   Dryden Marriage a-la-Mode iii. ii. 47   Pala. But who told you
>   I was here?..Rho. O, for that matter, we had intelligence.
>
> 1693   W. Congreve Old Batchelour iv. iv. 42   No, no, for that
>   matter—when she and I part, she'll carry her separate-maintenance
>   about her.
>
> 1758   C. Lennox Henrietta II. iii. i. 6   Nay, for that matter..I may
>   draw myself into another premune perhaps.
>
> 1791   A. Radcliffe Romance of Forest i. 17   La Motte..now earnestly
>   begged to know if his family were safe. ‘O! as for that matter they
>   are safe enough.’
>
> 1815   C. I. Johnstone Clan Albin I. xiv. 206   ‘Nay, for that
>   matter,’ said Moome,—‘Sky [i.e. Skye] was always namely for witches.’
>
> 1863   E. C. Gaskell Sylvia's Lovers III. vii. 108   Kinraid were just
>   fell again him, and as for that matter, so was I.
>
> 1898   Times 10 Jan. 13/3   The..shivering drivers..who (like every
>   one else, for that matter) had to lie out in it [sc. the rain] without
>   tents.
>
> 1913   J. Conrad Chance i. i. 14   Don't you think that my
>   colleague..wouldn't like to go up to this desk..four years in
>   advance?.. Or even one year for that matter.
>
> 1983   P. Marshall Praisesong for Widow i. 10   Her mind wasn't even
>   in her body, or for that matter, in the room.

Comment: @WS2- Thank you for answer. But you explained it in very high level. I didn't understand examples as those are out of context for me, moreover they have centuries like 1575..etc.  Starting of answer  _It is OED sense 3e of _ It's very tough still figuring out what was that 3e, OED, esp., 1575 G. Gascoigne Glasse of Gouernem. iv. iii. sig. Ji Dicke & why they need here. 
 :)

Comment: @Arvindraja The OED is the Oxford English Dictionary, perhaps the world's leading authority on the English language, as it is spoken around the world, together with the history and etymology of words.  EL & U is for serious linguists. If you are a relative beginner, you may find the sister site, *English Language Learners*, helpful.